# Bitbucket code ownership

Tags: ownership

Who is the owner of code uploaded from a personal account to a private Bitbucket repository and there is no license defined in the code, or there is only the name of the author in the header of the code? (based on that there is no any signed contract between the repository owner and the code owner)

Comment: Hi, Panagiotis, welcome to the site! Could you have a look at [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/1720/50) and see if that's basically the same as your question here? This question has some additional details about Bitbucket repos, but I don't think that changes the substance of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license)

Comment: More or less the context is the same, but my question is about a Bitbucket private repository (not GitHub).

Comment: The answer is basically the same whether it is GitHub, or Bitbucket or whether code is just posted on a random Web site.

Answer (score 1):

I am unsure whether you're asking who has the copyright or what you can do with the code.

Assuming this isn't a work-for-hire and assuming the copyright hasn't been transferred, the code belongs to the person or people who wrote it,  so presumably to the author.

Since you apparently have no license, you can't do anything with the code, except read it in place.

Comment: Thank you David for your answer, I suppose that the repository owner can't do anything with the code. While the code author (either mentioned in code header or not) has all the rights for the code.