# License for example implementations in C++ standard committee proposals?

Tags: licensing

I'd like to use some code in the example implementation section of a C++ standard committee proposal.  (Specifically, from [A Proposal to Add Y Combinator to the Standard Library](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0200r0.html).)

The paper itself is publically available but what is the license of the code contained therein?

(I am under the impression that this question would be off topic at SO.  But on this stack it is very hard to find a tag that fits the question, except the obvious one. Maybe that will change over time.)

Comment: Please see [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license)

Comment: For your specific example, it may also be the case that there is only one or a very small number of ways of implementing "y_combinator_result" and "y_combinator". Copyright only protects the creative elements of a work. For example, any C++ program will probably have "#include" directives required by the language, a class must have a "class" declaration, a "public" and "private" section, (optionally) a constructor, and so on. If you consider this, it may be difficult to find any protectable part of that implementation, so the license may not really matter in this case.