# Is Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular nuget package free or not?

Tags: licensing

I want to use nuget package with three .dll libraries https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Tabular/13.0.2150.2. It seems to be just additional pack to .net framework and doesn't seem to be under any special license.  But there is no any information about it. Google didn't help at all. Does anybody know its license? Not very sure 'Contact owners' will help me in the near future.

Comment: See also: [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend to avoid it.

If you download the package manually you can check that no License available in the whole package and no references to it. So for me, this is an `Unlicensed` case.

Also, you can check more information about the maintainer in the [Github profile](https://github.com/edberg).

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I cannot, because I need this MS API :( The reason why I hope there is all is ok with license because it is something official from Microsoft, there is a lot official documentation about .ddl-s, for example https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/bi-reference/tom/introduction-to-the-tabular-object-model-tom-in-analysis-services-amo

Comment: + mainteiner is some person we don't know, but Author(s) is Microsoft. But I don't know what is the difference.

Comment: Where did you saw that Microsoft is the author? This package isn't signed by Microsoft. Signed NuGet packages has a blue icon after the package title like these two: [NuGetAnalysisSrvs](https://www.nuget.org/profiles/NuGetAnalysisSrvs).

Also, check the [Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AnalysisServices.retail.amd64/) package. Contains the `dll`'s that you need.

Comment: thank you for the package, it helped!