# ZHST_IMS_Package license issue

Tags: licensing, license-compatibility, security

The ZHST_IMS_Package 1.0.0  was installed through Application insights nugget packages. As part of black duck scan found this has issue with license and reported as "License Not Found".

I found this component info at https://libraries.io/nuget/ZHST_IMS_Package but not provided license info.

What is the license of this package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license)

Comment: The ZHST_IMS_Package appears to be a collection of packages, probably dependencies for a project or another. As such, there probably isn't a singular license that covers ZHST_IMS_Package.