# Licence for youtube captions

Tags: copyright

Youtube allows creation of auto-generated captions. What are they licensed as? Is it cc0 or can one use them outside the video or to provide a transcript to users after ADA compliance editing.

Comment: Other than wishful thinking, what reason do you have for believing they might be CC0?

Comment: Just asking and guessing the     liscence of video captions generated by YouTube for the YouTuber.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I assume if a publicly published project has no license?](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license)

Comment: It actually does not because here it is said one cannot use it at all but in case of YouTube one can use it in their own videos .

Comment: For people thinking the thing is similar to github it is not as youtube allows usage of those captions in videos so then we are allowed but does not specify about the license for usage in other places.

Answer (score 2):

If these generated captions are mechanically created from (the audio track of) a video, then YouTube cannot claim any copyrights on those captions and therefor also not impose any copyright license terms.

This does not mean the captions are free of copyright, but their copyrights are fully owned by the copyright holders of the video (or possibly the copyright holders of the audio track).

Copyright law is intended to protect the human creativity that goes into creating something. As a purely mechanical transformation does not involve any human creativity (in *doing* the transformation), such transformations are generally excluded for copyright protection.

Comment: Hope this is the correct answer.

Comment: I am not challenging, but could you please state your qualifications for answering this question?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Internet_dog.jpg

Comment: What am I to understand from this cute image regarding the question I asked?

Answer (score 0):

They use the same license as the video.

Comment: Are you able to provide a reference for this?

Comment: No explicit description, but the above is probably the case.