# Using pretrained AllenNLP Coreference Resolution model commercially

Tags: licensing

I was wondering if anyone knows whether the current Coreference Resolution model on AllenNLP is commercially usable. All I know is that it is based on SpanBERT and SpanBERT itself has a CC-BY-NC license, but I am not sure whether this license is passed through to the trained model by AllenNLP.

Model card can be found [here.](https://demo.allennlp.org/coreference-resolution/coreference-resolution)

If the Coreference Resolution is for non-commercial use, do you have recommendations for other Coreference Resolution models? I have tried Spacy's neuralcoref and it performed poorly.

Comment: Please fix the link to the specific pretrained example of the model you're referring to, so we don't have to guess.  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, copied it from StackOverflow which got closed there, link got lost in the void.

Comment: Thank you for that, but I'd already found that link - I think it's to a running demo of the model, rather than to the distribution page for the code and training corpus of the model.  Could you perhaps link to the latter?  Or are you asking about using it as a web service that you call?

Comment: Yeah it is a running a demo of the model as listed below. They use a pre-trained model and what I would like to do is use that pre-trained on data. So, download the pretrained model and use the code around it to infer on. On the linked page you see a model-card tag which links to their public model. Further implementation on how to use the model locally and predict with it is based on the AllenNLP library which is commercially usable, however the base model might not be.

Comment: Forgive these questions, which must seem really stupid, but this is not my field.  The downloadable file linked from the "Model Card" tab contains a small `config.json` that makes no menton of licensing, a huge `weights.th` file which I assume is the trained state, and not much else.  Is it your intention to acquire a copy of the SpanBERT model code, feed it this state, and in some way use the result as part of your enterprise?

Comment: That is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found a trained-state corpus suitable for use with the [SpanBERT](https://github.com/facebookresearch/SpanBERT) tool, and want to know if you can use the combination inside your corporation.

I suspect not.  SpanBERT is, as you say, distributed under [CC BY-NC 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc/4.0/legalcode), and the trained-state corpus has no licence declaration on it at all.  That means you have no rights to download a copy of the former for commercial purposes, and [no rights at all](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/1720/what-can-i-assume-if-a-publicly-published-project-has-no-license) to use the latter.

The exact definition of "*commercial purposes*" is strewn with thorny interpretational problems, but the discussion is (a) off-topic for this site, and (b) irrelevant anyway, because of the absence of *any* permission to use the latter.  Sorry.

Comment: Thank you MadHatter for the clear and concise explanation.

Comment: You're welcome!